# ¿Por qué las propiedades CSS definidas para las etiquetas <a> no son aplicadas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estaba probando la función *addClass()* de JQuery cuando me percaté de que **las propiedades CSS definidas para la clase *.impares* se aplicaban sobre todos los enlaces y no solo sobre los impares**. El objetivo es diferenciar los enlaces impares de los pares mediante la adjudicación de propiedades CSS diferentes para cada conjunto a través de la mencionada función.

Pero entonces me fijé en que no era solo la clase *.impares* la que fallaba, sino también *#enlaces_de_prueba a*, pues el *margin-left* se aplica correctamente, pero no el *margin-bottom*.

No entiendo por qué no se aplican correctamente estas propiedades. Les dejo el **código** aquí. Está todo en una misma hoja exceptuando la librería JQuery, de la cual, por si fuera relevante, empleé la versión 3.6.0.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Prueba 3</title>
        
        <style type="text/css">
        
            *{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #botones{
                margin: 10px auto;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 50%;
                border: 2px solid black;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-around;
            }

            #pares, #impares{
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            #enlaces{
                margin: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 3px solid black;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-evenly;
            }

            #enlaces a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                background-color: burlywood;
            }

            #enlaces_de_prueba a{
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;/*NO FUNCIONA margin-bottom*/
            }

            /*NO FUNCIONA .impares o bien falla su llamada en el script de js*/
            .impares{
                color: chocolate;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }
        
        </style>

        <script src="C:\Users\DELL\Documents\VSC_Workspace\jquery.js"></script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(
                function(){
                    /*NO FUNCION la llamadao bien la clase está mal*/
                    $("#enlaces_de_prueba a:nth-child(2n+1)").addClass("impares");
                }
            );

        </script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="enlaces">
            <a href="Prueba_1.html">Prueba_1</a>
            <a href="Prueba_2.html">Prueba_2</a>
            <a href="Prueba_3.html">Prueba_3</a>
        </div>

        <div id="botones">
            <button type="button" id="pares">PARES</button>
            <button type="button" id="impares">IMPARES</button>
        </div>

        <div id="enlaces_de_prueba">
            <a href="https://www.google.es/" target="_blank">Google</a><br>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">YouTube</a><br>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">Instagram</a><br>
            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox" target="_blank">Gmail</a>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Gracias por su atención.

Comment: Esperen, que no han pasado ni dos minutos y he visto un error sintáctico. Lo he corregido y sigue sin funcionar la parte de CSS, aunque el error de Chrome ya no salta

Comment: `<script>src="C:\Users\DELL\Documents\VSC_Workspace\jquery.js"</script>`
La etiqueta `<script>`con la que cargas **JQuery** contiene un error tipográfico. Al tratar de usarlo sin tenerlo cargado la consola te arroja el error mencionado.

Comment: Lo sé. Mientras me escribías el comentario estaba escribiendo la corrección de la pregunta. Igualmente, las propiedades CSS no se aplican correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un par de problemas que te están ocasionando esos errores que nos mencionas, voy a tratar de desglosártelos:

1. La clase `.impares` se está añadiendo correctamente a tus enlaces. Si los revisas con el inspector de elementos de las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador, puedes ver que todas tus etiquetas `<a>` están recibiendo la mencionada clase. Entiendo que esto no es lo que pretendías, que lo que deseas es que se aplique solamente a los enlaces que sean impares. El problema respecto a esto lo tienes en que además de etiquetas `<a>`, el elemento `#enlaces_de_prueba` tiene como hijas etiquetas `<br>` que resulta que tienen posición par respecto a su padre. Por eso al usar el selector `#enlaces_de_prueba a:nth-child(2n+1)` estás ocasionando que la clase se aplique a todos los enlaces.

Para solucionarlo retiré las etiquetas `<br>`.

2. El `margin-bottom` de los enlaces de `#enlaces_de_prueba` se está aplicando correctamente, pero como dichos elementos no son de **bloque** el navegador hace caso omiso de dicha regla.

Para solucionarlo hice que dichos enlaces tuviesen `display: block`. Al haber quitado los `<br>` esto también provoca que los enlaces vayan cada uno en una línea diferente en vez de todos en la misma línea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Prueba 3</title>
        
        <style type="text/css">
        
            *{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #botones{
                margin: 10px auto;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 50%;
                border: 2px solid black;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-around;
            }

            #pares, #impares{
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            #enlaces{
                margin: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 3px solid black;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-evenly;
            }

            #enlaces a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                background-color: burlywood;
            }

            #enlaces_de_prueba a {
                display: block;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;/*NO FUNCIONA margin-bottom*/
            }

            /*NO FUNCIONA .impares o bien falla su llamada en el script de js*/
            .impares{
                color: chocolate;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }
        
        </style>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(
                function(){
                    /*NO FUNCION la llamadao bien la clase está mal*/
                    $("#enlaces_de_prueba a:nth-child(2n+1)").addClass("impares");
                }
            );

        </script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="enlaces">
            <a href="Prueba_1.html">Prueba_1</a>
            <a href="Prueba_2.html">Prueba_2</a>
            <a href="Prueba_3.html">Prueba_3</a>
        </div>

        <div id="botones">
            <button type="button" id="pares">PARES</button>
            <button type="button" id="impares">IMPARES</button>
        </div>

        <div id="enlaces_de_prueba">
            <a href="https://www.google.es/" target="_blank">Google</a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox" target="_blank">Gmail
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Desconocía que los elementos inline carecieran de la propiedad margin y desconocía también que el selector nth-child() considerase a todos los hijos independientemente de la etiqueta sobre la cual se defina. Pensaba que se aplicaba exclusivamente sobre dicha etiqueta, pero parece ser que para eso hay otro selector que ha explicado muy bien otro compañero en la respuesta de abajo. Gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás usando el selector `a:nth-child`, que obtiene todos los hijos, independientemente de su etiqueta y los saltos de línea también son tomados en cuenta. Solo necesitas cambiar a [a:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) para aplicar solo a los que correspondan con la etiqueta.

Además, se puede lograr desde CSS. En este fragmento de código se muestra solo con CSS, pero si necesitas hacerlo desde Javascript, solo elimina `, #enlaces_de_prueba a:nth-of-type(2n+1)` en las reglas CSS y descomenta el boque Javascript.

```js
/*
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        // Si lo quieres hacer con jQuery, solo cambia el selector
        $("#enlaces_de_prueba a:nth-of-type(2n+1)").addClass("impares");
    }
);
*/
```

```css
*{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #botones{
                margin: 10px auto;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 50%;
                border: 2px solid black;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-around;
            }

            #pares, #impares{
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            #enlaces{
                margin: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 3px solid black;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-evenly;
            }

            #enlaces a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                background-color: burlywood;
            }

            #enlaces_de_prueba a {
                display: inline-block; /* Para que funcionen los márgenes */
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            /* Se puede hacer solo con CSS */
            .impares, #enlaces_de_prueba a:nth-of-type(2n+1){
                color: chocolate;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="enlaces">
            <a href="Prueba_1.html">Prueba_1</a>
            <a href="Prueba_2.html">Prueba_2</a>
            <a href="Prueba_3.html">Prueba_3</a>
        </div>

        <div id="botones">
            <button type="button" id="pares">PARES</button>
            <button type="button" id="impares">IMPARES</button>
        </div>

        <div id="enlaces_de_prueba">
            <a href="https://www.google.es/" target="_blank">Google</a><br>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">YouTube</a><br>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">Instagram</a><br>
            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox" target="_blank">Gmail</a>
        </div>
```

Adicionalmente, no puedes aplicar margen a etiquetas que tienen la propiedad `display: inline;` y solo debes cambiar por otro valor tipo bloque, en este caso, `inline-block` es suficiente.

Para simplificar tu HTML, puedes eliminar los saltos de línea (`<br>`) y poner la propiedad `display: block;`, pero eso ya depende de tus requerimientos y preferencias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Desconocía que los elementos inline carecieran de la propiedad margin y desconocía también que el selector nth-child() considerase a todos los hijos independientemente de la etiqueta sobre la cual se defina. Su apunte sobre nth-of-type me será muy útil. Gracias de nuevo